# Force JSON Encode to Return Object

Tags: json

As far as I understand, Magento has a JSON encode function by using zend framework. And my question, is there an option to force that function always return JSON object, not JSON array?

```
Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
```

In native PHP (version 5.3.0 or above), I can achieve it by passing this constant "JSON_FORCE_OBJECT" into the second parameter of json_encode() function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe casting the array to an object could work?  Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode((object) $array);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsonEncode ends up using `Zend_Json_Encoder` here you will find a function `_encodeValue` which will either return an array or a object depending on the type of value.

```
protected function _encodeValue(&$value)
{
    if (is_object($value)) {
        return $this->_encodeObject($value);
    } else if (is_array($value)) {
        return $this->_encodeArray($value);
    }

    return $this->_encodeDatum($value);
}
```

So if there is a object passed in then there will be an object returned. This really helps with multiple levels. For example.

```
Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('test', 'blah')); => ["test","blah"]
Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode((object) array('test', 'blah')); => {"0":"test","1":"blah"}
Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('test', (object) 'blah')); => ["test",{"scalar":"blah"}]
```

Note that there are some special cases when encoding objects. [As explained on the zend docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.json.objects.html#encoding-php-objects)

> Encoding PHP objects If you are encoding PHP objects by default the
>   encoding mechanism can only access public properties of these objects.
>   When a method toJson() is implemented on an object to encode,
>   Zend\Json\Json calls this method and expects the object to return a
>   JSON representation of its internal state.
>
> Zend\Json\Json can encode PHP objects recursively but does not do so
>   by default. This can be enabled by passing true as a second argument
>   to Zend\Json\Json::encode().
>
> // Encode PHP object recursively $jsonObject =
>   Zend\Json\Json::encode($data, true); When doing recursive encoding of
>   objects, as JSON does not support cycles, an
>   Zend\Json\Exception\RecursionException will be thrown. If you wish,
>   you can silence these exceptions by passing the
>   silenceCyclicalExceptions option:

Comment: A very helpful information, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Another method I found and worked like a charm.

```
$this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json', true);
$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($array));
```